# How to use WebView to detect dynamic html updates?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

Trying to monitor and control some projectors, each with a web server built in. The status of the projectors is updated to a page dynamically through javascript.

I managed to retrieve the html and zero in on the status I was looking for using a WebView object. However, when the status changes, I will need to refresh my values, but I can't' seem to find any event that would detect such changes.

For example, when I first access the power on/off status, it's shown as Unknown and won't be updated to on/off until several seconds after the - (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame event.

I can setup a timer to poll the values, but I would prefer to have it trigger by some sort of an event (or observe any value change). Are there such events? I looked in into WebView, WebFrame, but can't seem to find any.

Or is there a way to observe a javascript variable? The values I'm looking for are stored in javascript variables.

Or perhaps any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not in control of the JavaScript I doubt you can raise an event in response to an AJAX call. I guess you'll have to periodically look for changes using `NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:`. Example, to get the value of `varName` run the following:

```
NSString *value = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"varName"];
```

Comment: I guess that's the only way… Thank you.

Comment: can this also check for certain fields in my html?

Answer (score 1):

If you can find any JS hooks / dom events that are fired when your content changes you can open a URL with a custom scheme (e.g. "refresh://content") from JS and implement the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` in which you can check the scheme.

If you can't find any proper events you should really just poll the JS variable values every 5-10 seconds via `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"js_variable_name"]`

Comment: I guess that's the only way, thanx for helping out.